# Measure page time in vue

Tags: vue.js

Previously, I measure page time using jQuery unload method

For example :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var start = new Date();
});

$(window).unload(function() {
  var end = new Date();
});
```

Now I want to make the same thing as vue

But vue destroyed does not seem to be jQuery unload method.

How do I measure page time with vue?

Comment: What about the performance panel in the dev tools window of any browser ?

Comment: Because it is for logging

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your previous method is not perfect either because such `**$(document)**` construction require jquery to be loaded.

The same things for Vue.js. It is not going to measure page timings right from the start, because it has to be loaded.

So you can't measure page loading accurately. You can use that:

```
let start = performance.now();
window.addEventListener('unload', function() {
  alert(performance.now() - start);
});
```

And place this code inside `<head>` tag before any scripts and styles.